# Chaining methods in LinqtoSql: How to get entity context

Tags: c#, linq, generics, audit

I have an Audit library I am working with.  I believe this question is more to do with generics, as I'm not sure how to write methods similar to the ones in question.

I have the following "chained" methods and can't seem to get a context to a lookup table:

```
AuditProperty(m => m.StationTypeId)
.GetValueFrom(stationtypeId => GetStationType(stationtypeId))
.WithPropertyName("StationType");
```

The idea is to pass an ID into the GetValueFrom() linq method, and return a string from the (in this case) stationtype table.  I have gotten it to work by assigning a static table to the actual Stationtype table at runtime (which is stationTypeTable, below), so I can perform a lookup like so:

```
public string GetStationType(int? stationTypeID)
        {

            var stationtype = stationTypeTable.FirstOrDefault(st => object.Equals(st.Id, stationTypeID));
            return stationtype != null ? stationtype.Value : String.Empty;
        }
```

I know this is bad practice.  I have been getting exceptions when some primary key ID's don't exist.  But, I can't actually seem to get a context to any table when I call the linq methods.  Any idea how I can do this correctly?  The linq methods are below for your reference:

```
public class EntityAuditConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityAuditConfiguration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Customize the default behavior when auditing a specific property
    /// </summary>
    public CustomPropertyAuditor<TEntity, T> AuditProperty<T>(Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> propertySelector)
    {
        var config = new CustomPropertyAuditor<TEntity, T>();
        CustomizedProperties.Add(propertySelector.ToPropertyInfo(), config);
        return config;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Include an association (relationship) table to audit along with the parent table
    /// </summary>
    public RelatationshipConfiguration<TChildEntity, TEntity> AuditMany<TChildEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TChildEntity>>> selector)
        where TChildEntity : class
    {
        var relationship = new RelatationshipConfiguration<TChildEntity, TEntity>();
        ((IEntityAuditConfiguration) this).Relationships.Add(relationship);
        return relationship;
    }
}



public class CustomPropertyAuditor<TEntity, TProp> : IPropertyAuditor
{
    private Expression<Func<TProp, string>> _propertySelector;
    private string _propertyName;

    public CustomPropertyAuditor<TEntity, TProp> WithPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
        _propertyName = propertyName;
        return this;
    }


    public CustomPropertyAuditor<TEntity, TProp> GetValueFrom(Expression<Func<TProp, string>> valueSelector)
    {
        if (valueSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");
        _propertySelector = valueSelector;
        return this;
    }

    AuditedProperty IPropertyAuditor.AuditProperty(PropertyInfo property, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var auditedProperty = new AuditedProperty(_propertyName ?? property.Name);
        var func = _propertySelector.Compile();

        if (oldValue != null)
            auditedProperty.OldValue = func.DynamicInvoke(oldValue).ToString();

        if (newValue != null)
            auditedProperty.NewValue = func.DynamicInvoke(newValue).ToString();

        return auditedProperty;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: At least give me a reference where I can learn exactly how to create these types of methods!

Comment: I FIXED it by simply creating a list and adding each row to the list in the oncreate() method of my class. These lookup tables should be available in the context and I shouldn't have to create a separate lookup list. Anyone have any other ideas? I guess not?

Answer (score 0):

I simply created a list and added each row to the list in the oncreate() method of my class. These lookup tables should be available in the context and I shouldn't have to create a separate lookup list(but it works 100% now). Anyone have any other better ideas?